# Show new pricing table on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to have two pricing tables on a website but to have only one active/showing.

It would need to function like a slider, so when the arrow is clicked next pricing table is loaded and shown.

I would need some snippet for this that would work with Bootstrap 3.

I'm using this table http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-30-responsive-pricing-tables and the code for the table:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                    <!-- PRICE ITEM -->
                    <div class="panel price panel-red">
                        <div class="panel-heading  text-center">
                        <h3>PRO PLAN</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$10 / month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Personal use</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /PRICE ITEM -->


                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                    <!-- PRICE ITEM -->
                    <div class="panel price panel-blue">
                        <div class="panel-heading arrow_box text-center">
                        <h3>DEV PLAN</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$20 / month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-info"></i> Personal use</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-info"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-info"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /PRICE ITEM -->


                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                    <!-- PRICE ITEM -->
                    <div class="panel price panel-green">
                        <div class="panel-heading arrow_box text-center">
                        <h3>FREE PLAN</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$0 / month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Personal use</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /PRICE ITEM -->


                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                    <!-- PRICE ITEM -->
                    <div class="panel price panel-grey">
                        <div class="panel-heading arrow_box text-center">
                        <h3>FREE PLAN</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$0 / month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Personal use</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /PRICE ITEM -->


                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                    <!-- PRICE ITEM -->
                    <div class="panel price panel-white">
                        <div class="panel-heading arrow_box text-center">
                        <h3>FREE PLAN</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$0 / month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Personal use</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /PRICE ITEM -->


                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                    <!-- PRICE ITEM -->
                    <div class="panel price panel-white">
                        <div class="panel-heading arrow_box text-center">
                        <h3>FREE PLAN</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$0 / month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Personal use</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /PRICE ITEM -->


                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                    <!-- PRICE ITEM -->
                    <div class="panel price panel-white">
                        <div class="panel-heading arrow_box text-center">
                        <h3>FREE PLAN</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$0 / month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Personal use</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /PRICE ITEM -->


                </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                    <!-- PRICE ITEM -->
                    <div class="panel price panel-white">
                        <div class="panel-heading arrow_box text-center">
                        <h3>FREE PLAN</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$0 / month</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Personal use</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-success"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /PRICE ITEM -->


                </div>


            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Where is your code? Please post what you've tried and your current code so we can help.

Comment: The hidden table is loaded with every click on the button?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida I have only html code for the table. I was unable to find the right jQuery function to load my next table. I've added the code in the original post

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina Yes, hidden table should be loaded on click and replaced with the old one, same as rotating sliders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used the bootstrap carousel and kept all your `pricing table` inside each item of the carousel and after seeing the result I just assume that, this is what you want!! The code is too long to post here So I'll just post this **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n8263de1/2/)** for your reference and this **[FULL SCREEN RESULT](https://jsfiddle.net/n8263de1/2/embedded/result/)** to check for responsiveness.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion of the BT carousel. This is what I needed!